# How to map properties that belongs to fields of the join table of a many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have a table bills and a table documents. A bill can be related with many documents and a document can be related with many bills. A many to many relationship.

Also, in the join table, a have a field, page, that indicates the page in which the document has information about the related bill.

So in my database I have this:

- Bills(Id, Reference...)
- Documents(Id, Name...)
- DocumentsOfBills(IdBill, IdDocument, Page)

Now this is my entities in which map the tables:

```
public class Bill
{
    long Id;
    string Reference;

    HashSet<Document> Documents;
}



public class Document
{
    long Id;
    string Name;
}
```

if I don't inlcude the page, I know how to configure this relationship with fluent API and EF Core 7:

```
internal class BillConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Bill>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Bill> paramBillfiguracion)
    {
        paramFacturafiguracion.ToTable("Bills");


        paramBillfiguracion.HasKey(o => o.Id);
        paramBillfiguracion.Property<long>(o => o.Id)
            .HasColumnName("Id")
            .HasColumnType("bigint")
            .IsRequired();

        paramBillfiguracion.Property<string?>(o => o.Reference)
            .HasColumnName("Reference")
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");


            paramBillfiguracion
                .HasMany(x => x.Documents)
                .WithMany()
                .UsingEntity(
                    "DocumentsOfBills",
                    l => l.HasOne(typeof(Document)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("Id").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Document.Id)),
                    r => r.HasOne(typeof(Bill)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("Id").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Bill.Id)),
                    j => j.HasKey("IdDocument", "IdBill"));
    }
}
```

The problem is How to include the page in the document. I was thinking to add the property page in the Document entity:

```
public class Document
{
    long Id;
    string Name;
    int Page;
}
```

But I don't know how to configure that using fluent API. how to configure to set the page in the entity property? Is it possible to do it in this way? I would like to avoid the needed to have a join entity only to has access to the page number.

Thanks.

Comment: If the entity has additional properties, it is no more just "join" entity, but actual entity having many-to-one relationships with two other entities. So you must model it that way - explicit entity, no skip navigations, regular one-to-many collection navigation properties in both entities etc.

Comment: @daniherrera all the answer uses an entity for the join table, as Ivan Stoev suggests to do. How ever I found the way to do it without the need to use this entity. i will create an answer to show the code.

Comment: Hola Álvaro, gracias por documentar la respuesta. He retirado el voto to close. Gracias por compartir. Veo que está documentado aquí: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-class-for-join-entity

Comment: @daniherrera Welcome. The documentation it is good, but I guess this specific case it is a bit hard to get without some tries, so I thought it would be interesting to share. Thanks for quit the vote to close the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, all the solutions that I have seen use a an entity for the join table, but i would like to avoid this because it makes to have larger code because you have to navigate for different properties.

The solution is using Entity Core 7, but I don't know if it works in an earlier version.

This are my entities:

```
public class Bill
{
    long Id;
    string Reference;

    HashSet<Document> Documents;
}



public class Document
{
    long Id;
    string Name;
    int page;
}
```

This is the configuration of for Bills:

```
internal class BillConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Bill>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Bill> paramBillfiguracion)
    {
        paramFacturafiguracion.ToTable("Bills");


        paramBillfiguracion.HasKey(o => o.Id);
        paramBillfiguracion.Property<long>(o => o.Id)
            .HasColumnName("Id")
            .HasColumnType("bigint")
            .IsRequired();

        paramBillfiguracion.Property<string?>(o => o.Reference)
            .HasColumnName("Reference")
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");


            paramBillfiguracion
                .HasMany(x => x.Documents)
                .WithMany()
                .UsingEntity(
                    "DocumentsOfBills",
                    l => l.HasOne(typeof(Document)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("Id").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Document.Id)),
                    r => r.HasOne(typeof(Bill)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("Id").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Bill.Id)),
                    j => j.HasKey("IdDocument", "IdBill"));
    }
}
```

This is the configuration for document. It is where is the key part:

```
internal class ConfiguracionDocuments : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Document>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Document> paramDocumentConfiguracion)
    {
        paramDocumentConfiguracion.ToTable("Documents")
            .SplitToTable("DocumentsOfBills",
                TableBuilder =>
                {
                    TableBuilder.Property(document => document.Id).HasColumnName("IDDocument");
                    TableBuilder.Property(document => document.Page).HasColumnName("Page");
                });


        paramDocumentConfiguracion.HasKey(o => o.Id);
        //Se indica que el ID lo asingará la base de datos al agregar la entidad.
        paramDocumentConfiguracion.Property<long>(o => o.Id)
            .HasColumnName("IDDocument")
            .HasColumnType("bigint")
            .IsRequired();

        paramDocumentConfiguracion.Property<string>(o => o.Name)
            .HasColumnName("Name")
            .HasColumnType("varchar(900)")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

And specificly, this is the important part:

```
    paramDocumentConfiguracion.ToTable("Documents")
        .SplitToTable("DocumentsOfBills",
            TableBuilder =>
            {
                TableBuilder.Property(document => document.Id).HasColumnName("IDDocument");
                TableBuilder.Property(document => document.Page).HasColumnName("Page");
            });
```

Here I am telling that the Document entity use two table to get the data, with SplitTable.

```
TableBuilder.Property(document => document.Id).HasColumnName("IDDocument");
```

This stablish the relation between the join table and the documents table. Personally I prefer to set it, but in this case it is not really needed because is set in the bills configuration, when I set the many to many relationship.

```
TableBuilder.Property(document => document.Page).HasColumnName("Page");
```

In this line I set that the Page property in the Document entity get the data from the field of the join table in the database.

The documentation is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting#configuration-1

I hope this code could help.